# Visual studio code connect to AWS ec2 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

I tried to connect to my ec2 instance use visual studio code. I always get errors "trying to write on nonexistence pipe"

```
Host personal
  HostName ec2-18-237-4-7.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  User ec2-user
  IdentityFile C:\Users\username\keys\new_amazon.pem
```

Those codes I found it on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_getting-started
so I got that error above what can I do to fix it in my visual studio code.

Comment: Are you able to SSH to the instance from the command line using `ssh -i C:\Users\username\keys\new_amazon.pem ec2-user@ec2-18-237-4-7.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Now I did that command in CMD and it connects successfully. I don't know what to do

Comment: I disabled inheritance in config.file properties but now it tells me an error  of that "EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\PATIENCE\.ssh\config')"    If I enabled it I got error of " bad owner or invalid permission"